# Add, Commit & Push to git repository on save

Tags: visual-studio-code

In one git repository (workspace), I want every save committed ASAP. What is the easiest way to achieve that with VSCode?

So, when I press CTRL + S, it gets pushed upstream.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done with plugin [Run on Save](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=pucelle.run-on-save)

Here is the example that auto commits and pushes upstream any changes in the directory `mydir`:

```json
"emeraldwalk.runonsave": {
        "commands": [
            {
                "match": "\\\\mydir\\\\",
                "isAsync": false,
                "cmd": "cd ${fileDirname}",
            }, 
            {
                "match": "\\\\mydir\\\\",
                "isAsync": false,
                "cmd": "git add -A",
            },
            {
                "match": "\\\\mydir\\\\",
                "isAsync": false,
                "cmd": "git commit -a -m \"vscode autosave\"",
            },
            {
                "match": "\\\\mydir\\\\",
                "isAsync": false,
                "cmd": "git push",
            }
        ]
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

One way to achieve that is via terminal on VSCode. Change to the topmost directory containing the .git file and run the following commands:

```
git status
```

This shall show you the uncommitted changes. Then run the following for the new added changes (except for the remove changes)

```
git add <fileName>
```

This shall add all the added contents to index.
Run below for the remove changes.

```
git rm <filename>
```

Then, `git commit -m <commit msg>` to commit the changes.

Comment: I know how to do it from the CLI, that is not the point. I want ctrl + s and done.